# I need a SQL server Func that will calculate a complete date from the week of the year

Tags: sql-server

I need to calculate to a string of dd-MM-yyyy

From a wwyy string (I need the first day of the week or any other day of the week)

for exmpl: Now we are in week 42 of 18 so if I'll enter 4218
I'll get 15-10-2018 or 14-10-2018

BR,
Idan

Comment: Ok, and have you encountered a particular issue whilst writing one? SO isn't a code writing service - I'd suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask], then providing a [mcve]

Comment: So a programmer is in need of yet another programmer? Perhaps you will find that the definition of "week" is not as consistent as you assume.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @input char(4) set @input = 4218

SET DATEFIRST 1
declare @wk int  set @wk = cast(SUBSTRING(@input,1,2) as int)
declare @yr int  set @yr = 2000 + cast(SUBSTRING(@input,3,2) as int)

select dateadd (week, @wk, dateadd (year, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4 -
         datepart(dw, dateadd (week, @wk, dateadd (year, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Make separate from code side and use in below query to achieve your result.

```
DECLARE @WeekNo int= 42
DECLARE @Year int=2018

SELECT CAST(DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0)) AS DATE) AS first_day_of_week
```